# Error cannot find "%>%" when knitting to html?

Tags: html, filter, knitr, pdb

Sorry I am quite a beginner with R:

It runs in the R-markdown, but when I want to knit it to html, it gives this:

Error in pdb %>% filter(human, canonical_marker...
could not find function "%>%" Calls  ...withVisible -> eval_with_user_handlers -> eval -> eval Execution halted

Here the code:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```
# Install packages
if (!requireNamespace("devtools", quietly = TRUE)) {
  install.packages("devtools")
}
if (!requireNamespace("Seurat", quietly = TRUE)) {
  install.packages("Seurat")
}
if (!requireNamespace("OmnipathR", quietly = TRUE)) {
  devtools::install_github("saezlab/OmnipathR")
}
if (!requireNamespace("decoupleR", quietly = TRUE)) {
  devtools::install_github("saezlab/decoupleR")
}
if (!requireNamespace("dplyr", quietly = TRUE)) {
  install.packages("dplyr")
}
  
if (!requireNamespace("tibble", quietly = TRUE)) {
  install.packages("tibble")
}
if (!requireNamespace("tidyr", quietly = TRUE)) {
  install.packages("tidyr")
}
if (!requireNamespace("ggplot2", quietly = TRUE)) {
  install.packages("ggplot2")
}
if (!requireNamespace("pheatmap", quietly = TRUE)) {
  install.packages("pheatmap")
}
if (!requireNamespace("patchwork", quietly = TRUE)) {
  install.packages("patchwork")
}
if (!requireNamespace("ggrepel", quietly = TRUE)) {
  install.packages("ggrepel")
}

# Load dependencies
library (devtools)
library(OmnipathR)
library(Seurat)
library(decoupleR)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
library(pheatmap)
library(patchwork)
library(ggrepel)
```

```
data <- readRDS('~/data.rds')
data
```

```
# Get resource from OmniPath
pdb <- decoupleR::get_resource(name='PanglaoDB')
pdb
```

```
pdb <- pdb %>% 
  filter(human, canonical_marker, organ == 'Immune system') %>% 
  distinct(cell_type, genesymbol)

pdb
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late but I thought I'd leave an answer.

I run your exact code and it executed correctly with no errors.
Maybe try to re-install the "magrittr" package.

Btw are you getting this error only when knitting the markdown?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.